# Is compact $T_1$ topological space hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm in a middle of a very hard exercise which its goal is to prove that some space is hausdorff, but all I could show is that it is $T_1$. But I can also deduce that it is compact.
Is that enough for a space to be hausdorff?
It accured to me that $T_2$+compact implies $T_4$, so it is reasonable for such connections to be true, yet I couldn't think of a proof for that.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: an infinite space with the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) is compact and $T_1$ but not Hausdorff.

Comment: Is the set $\left \{ \frac{1}{n} \right \}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \cup \{0 \}$ a counterexample (with the cofinite topology)?  I don't think you can separate $0$ from any other point via Hausdorffness.

Comment: @user46944: That set does not have the cofinite topology: it’s only at $0$ that the topology is cofinite. And you can separate $0$ from each of the other points. For example, $\left(-1,\frac1{n+1}\right)$ and $\left(\frac1{n+1},2\right)$ are disjoint open nbhds of $0$ and $\frac1n$.

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought you can declare the cofinite topology on any set, and this forms a topology.  Is that not true?

Comment: @user46944: Yes, it’s true. But the usual topology on $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ is not the cofinite topology.

Comment: Sure.  In my initial comment I meant you declare that the set has the cofinite topology (as opposed to the usual one).  I was wondering if this one isn't Hausdorff.  It doesn't seem like it is Hausdorff, so it would be an explicit example of your answer.

Comment: @user46944: Ah, okay; that wasn’t clear. Sure, take any specific infinite set; $\Bbb N$ would be a simpler choice. Then give it the cofinite topology, and you’ll have a $T_1$ space that isn’t Hausdorff. (In fact a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$ is $T_1$ if and only if the cofinite topology on $X$ is a subset of $\tau$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the discussion. I have posted my full question in a different thread, if you would like to try and solve.

Comment: @TopologyGetsMeTired: You’re welcome; I’ll take a look.